# How to create EER model from a sqlite db

Tags: java, sqlite, entity-relationship, reverse-engineering, eer-model

i'm using [sqlitejdbc libraries](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) to create a db using java.
Now i need to generate eer model from existing sqlite db stored in a file.
In past i used MySqlWorkbench to generate eer from a mysql db, but i don't know how to do that on sqlite db.. can someone help me? thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. **Open SQLite file using SQLite Database Browser**
2. **Export to SQL**
3. **Import (using plugin) into Workbench**

Details:

If you have the sqlite file available, open it using the free [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/). This gives you a few ways in which to inspect the database:

- view table structure
- view table content
- issue queries against content
- and more...

Beyond this, you can opt for the SQL file export. Go to "File > Export > Database to SQL file" option inside the SQLite Database Browser.

Once you create the SQL output file, use the [SQLite export plugin for MySQL Workbench](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?155,262396) - especially if you're already familiar with MySQL's Workbench tool.

Comment: I feel so dumb not being able to find this solution by myself... It's very smart, simple and very efficient. Thanks a lot

Comment: Wish SQLite database browser had an ER visualizer itself.